# Cart page in PHP

Tags: php

Just because of one condition I am stack. Suppose I am in pid=1. then I go to pid=2. so now our previousID is 1. If I click again PID=2 then how can I get that previousID that means previousID=1? And I have to check whether I came from PID=1 or PID=3. Because user can come to PID=2 from PID=1 or PID=3. 
There is one condition need but I am stack on that.
It's not coming.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I think you should visit this first
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include your code if you wish to get an answer.